# li items of different height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to allow `li`items to have the same width but different height that may include images and text. the problem is when i float left, or display:inline-block, and one of the item exceeds the height. It disturbs the visual style of the content. Is there any way where i can manage this?

I want the li to follow a simple rule as

```
li {
    float:left;
    display:list-item;
    width:200px;
    background:#CCC;
    height:auto;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

The example website which includes the same is

[Genny Website](http://www.genny.com/en/inside)

Comment: Genny Website uses absolute position to get that desired effect. I'm not sure if you can do that without some javascript tricks. @Michael Peterson's answer is probably the simplest solution with out to much javascript.

Answer (score 4):

Sites like genny.com and pinterest.com do NOT float their elements, but rather position them absolutely and set their `left` and `top` values dynamically through JS. First, they grab the count of elements on the page. Second, they sniff the `height` and `width` of the elements. Third, they change the `left` and `top` CSS values.

+1 for the [Masonry](http://vanilla-masonry.desandro.com/) answer, I just wanted to explain how it works.

Answer (score 3):

[jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) will be what you're looking for here, by nature the li's will never really bump up to the one above them without some less-than desirable code, but that jQuery plugin makes it very simple.

Comment: As this is not tagged with jQuery, you should link to http://vanilla-masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 3):

I think you would need to create three columns. something like:

```
<ul id="first column">
    <li>Some content</li>
    <li>Some content</li>
   . . .
</ul>
<ul id="second column">
    <li>Some content</li>
    <li>Some content</li>
   . . .
</ul>
<ul id="third column">
    <li>Some content</li>
    <li>Some content</li>
   . . .
</ul>
```

Then you shouldn't have to float the li tags.

Comment: Ok, I like Alexander Wigmore's answer